# Extended an encrypted partition, why the disk space is unused?

Tags: disk-utility, partition, encryption

My primary partition is encrypted with FileVault2, and the other one is not. When I extend the primary partition, it succeed, but the space is actually not in use.

I have 250GB

[image]

But only 229 GB is used,

[image]

### EDIT

```
 %> gpt -r show disk0

    start       size  index  contents
        0          1         PMBR
        1          1         Pri GPT header
        2         32         Pri GPT table
       34          6
       40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
   409640  448053928      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
448463568   41509000      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
489972568     262151
490234719         32         Sec GPT table
490234751          1         Sec GPT header

%> diskutil cs list
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 82137BFD-8113-495B-9400-51D7232F9AD7
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Online
    Size:         229403611136 B (229.4 GB)
    Free Space:   0 B (0 B)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 01C5097D-2D17-4D71-AFAF-CD3D215F04A7
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     229403611136 B (229.4 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family 7851B866-EF98-4DE7-A428-A5F2C1893D63
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
        Encryption Status:       Unlocked
        Conversion Status:       Complete
        High Level Queries:      Fully Secure
        |                        Passphrase Required
        |                        Accepts New Users
        |                        Has Visible Users
        |                        Has Volume Key
        |
        +-> Logical Volume 0AC1C7E8-62B4-405E-9826-4B8C3D1B804A
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk1
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          229068066816 B (229.1 GB)
            Revertible:            Yes (unlock and decryption required)
            LV Name:               Macintosh HD
            Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

Comment: @klanomath added to the question. I use Disk Utility to do that

Comment: @klanomath So I have to turn off filevault and turn it on again?

Comment: @klanomath done

Answer (score 1):

Immediately (**no reboot!**) backup your main volume with Time Machine to an external volume.

Boot to Internet Recovery Mode, erase your disk and restore the backup.

---

Your Recovery Partition (size: 41509000 blocks/21.25 GB, index 3) seems to be hosed but holds some invisible intermediate encryption/decryption keys for your encrypted  main volume. Usually this partition is much smaller (size: 1269536 blocks/650 MB) and has a different ending block. So the boundaries of the Recovery Partition may have been moved without moving the content of it. Consequently it's saver to backup and restore!

Unless you don't reboot this is no problem.